# Why is my ruby on rails app not rendering rails code in my partial html page?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, zurb-foundation, csrf-protection

I am new to rails and following the tutorials from Micheal Hartl. In his tutorials he uses the 'form_for' tags to create forms in his app. However, I love the css frameworks and thus decided to use Zurb Foundation for creating a form in HTML manually. The form is created inside a modal. Here is the code for the form:

```
<div class="reveal" id="StudentLoginModal" data-reveal
  data-animation-in="hinge-in-from-top" data-animation-out="hinge-out-from-bottom">

  <form data-abide novalidate action="/login" method="POST">
    <%= form_authenticity_token %>
    <div data-abide-error class="alert callout" style="display: none;">
      <p><i class="fi-alert"></i> There are some errors in your form.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="row">

        <label style="font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.15em;
        font-weight: bold;">UserName
        <input name="session[name]" type="text" placeholder="Your Exam Roll.no" required pattern="number"
        aria-describedby= "exampleHelpText">
        <span class="form-error">
          Yo, you had better fill this out, it's required.
        </span>
        <p class="help-text" id="exampleHelpText">Enter your username.</p>
      </label>

      <label style="font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 1.15em;
      font-weight: bold;">Password
      <input type="password" name="session[password]" id="password" placeholder="yeti4preZ" aria-describedby= "exampleHelpText1" required >
      <span class="form-error">
        I'm required!
      </span>
      <p class="help-text" id="exampleHelpText1">Enter a password please.</p>
    </label>
    <input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit">
  </div>
 </form>

   <button class="close-button" data-close aria-label="Close reveal"  type="button">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
   </button>

</div>
```

But the problem is that rails has CSRF protection and it doesn't allows users to submit form without an authenticity token. I have tried retrieving the value using <%= form_authenticity_token %> but it doesn't add any values to the form. However, the tag is showing the value of token in other pages. Any Ideas?

Thanks :)

Edit 1: I think the problem is the modal I am using to render the login form.

Comment: you can put `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` in your controller.

Comment: But that would turn-off the CSRF. Isn't that not advised?

Answer (score 0):

Use
`<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>">`
instead of `<%= form_authenticity_token %>`

Comment: Are you rendering this form using ajax request?

Comment: Well the click on login button is handled by foundation library, so I don't know if they are using AJAX or not but the click displays a modal so I think it is Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

## in controller

```
def my_action
  @auth_token_form = form_authenticity_token
end
```

## in view

```
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%=form_authenticity_token %>">
```

Comment: Not working either. I think it is not showing the code because of the modal I am using to render the form.

Comment: `form_authenticity_token()`  is only accessible in the Controllers (class: ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection).